# VS code marks error and can't find solution CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am really new to programming and I am having some difficulties. Even when I try to recreate code from other sources it seems to not work for me, when I am following a step by step tutorial, so please be patient. This is the css for a loading bar

```
    background: black;
}

.progress{
    --progress: 0%;
    width: 500px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 9em auto;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aaa;
}

.progress .bar {
    width: var(--progress);
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(gold, #c85, gold );
    background-repeat: repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px orange;
    animation: shine 4s ease-in infinite, end 1s ease-out 1 7s;
    transition: widths 3s ease 3s;
}

@property --progress {
    syntax: "<length>";
    initial-value: 0%;
    inherits: true;
}

@keyframes shine {
    0%{
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100%{
        background-position: 0 50px;
    }

}

@keyframes end {
    0%,
    100%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px orange;
    }
    50%{
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5 px orange;
    }
}
```

**@property** keeps showing like an error and i don't know why. Just to be clear, is in this fragment:

```
@property --progress {
    syntax: "<length>";
    initial-value: 0%;
    inherits: true;
}
```

Sorry, this is my first post and English is not my first language.

Comment: I don't think @property is supported on some browsers - see https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property

Comment: Does VScode display some kind of error? Furthermore, @property is experimental. You should't use it in production, imo.